# how to Post data from wordpress to other server(mysql) database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a word press plugin where i have some data to be saved in another mysql server database.Simply the data have to be saved in another MySql server's database table.Hope i am Clear.How can i approach to this progrmmatically.Any suggestions are highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read up on PHP's methods for creating a database connection.  Once you establish an additional database connection (using IP, port, and login credentials for the second database), you'll be able to interface with it through SQL.  You'll be able to assign the new database connection to a handle so you can easily control which database you're sending the SQL queries to and avoid communicating with the wrong one.

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure you asked the right question...you didn't mean to say that you want to store the data to a different "table" did you?  Because you said a different database, which is completely separate from the wordpress database.

Comment: i want to save the data from wordpress server to another server database table.

Comment: So a different table in the same database?  If its the same database but only a different table, then you don't want to make a new database connection.

Comment: If you're going to use the Wordpress database and just add an additional table, then you need to write a SQL query to check for an existing table and make it if its missing as a first-time initialization.  Once the table is created, all you gotta do is have your main code do SQL queries to add and read from the table in question.

Answer (score 0):

Please make a new database connection with new instance and save data with other database.
for eg.

```
$dbh1 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password); 
$dbh2 = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, true); 

mysql_select_db('database1', $dbh1);
mysql_select_db('database2', $dbh2);
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh1);
mysql_query('select * from tablename', $dbh2);
```